# Request call fails on Task queue with Connection aborted, Permission denied

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-requests

When I am making a direct call to the OpenCalais API, it all seems to be fine and I get a 200 request.

However the moment I put the same code on a GAE Task queue, something strange happens:

```
response = requests.post('https://api.thomsonreuters.com/permid/calais/',
                                     data=news.body.encode('utf8'),
                                     timeout=60,
                                     headers={'x-ag-access-token': 'xxx',
                                              'content-type': 'TEXT/RAW',
                                              'outputFormat': 'Application/JSON',
                                              'enableMetadataType': 'SocialTags'})
```

The line throws right away an exception:

```
('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

At first I thought I might be hitting the api too many times per second. So I set a break point there. But the very first call to the API breaks with that exception. I don't understand why, because when I execute that function directly it can connect to the API seamlessly with a 200 return.

I have been in touch with the OpenCalais support and they can see there has been 13 successful requests, which are the manual ones. But they don't see any error/failures in the log. So it is definitely on my side. But what could it be?

Comment: how are you authenticating to the API? it seems the Google Server is missing some token/cookie you already have.

Comment: Requests is not guaranteed to work on GAE. GAE is not Python and only provides certain APIs that we need access to at a cost to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a defect on GAE.  If I downgrade to `requests 2.1.0` it works fine on GAE.

I have raised the bug with GAE. Feel free to star the issue to push for a fix.

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11942&thanks=11942&ts=1431082804

Comment: What changed between the versions of the requests library you were using and 2.1.0? What makes you think it's a bug in GAE?

Comment: Its easy. Click on the link in my answer and see that google has confirmed the bug in GAE.